# git: How do I "see" a remote branch?

Tags: git, fetch

On Azure, I've created a new branch based on a master branch.

From my desktop I then ran:

```
git fetch
```

I expected to see the remote branch when I run:

```
git branch -l
```

...but I don't. I then tried:

```
git branch -r
```

... to see remote branches. My branch is still not listed.

I'm really not understanding why the above commands don't work, what command should I be using?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -r`?
It would include your branch but with a `<remote>/<branch-name>`, e.g. `origin/my_branch`

Comment: `git branch -l` is the same as without the `-l` and that shows your *local* branches only, so that shouldn't display the new upstream branch you created on Azure. But `git fetch` should have listed the new branch in its output the first time you fetched after the upstream branch was created, and `git branch -r` should have displayed it too. Can you show the output?

Answer (score 1):

Git overuses the word *branch* so heavily that it largely loses all meaning.  [It's like being at a party where everyone is named Bruce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ojhtq51Ya8).  We have to be super-careful with this word.

Now, the thing to know about Git is that a Git *repository* is, at its heart, a collection of *commits*.  The commits are what Git is all about.  They're numbered, and each one has two things:

- a snapshot of all files, frozen for all time; and
- some metadata (information *about* the commit), also frozen for all time.

The numbers are big, ugly, random-looking things (*hash IDs* or *OIDs*) that are impossible for humans to remember or deal with sensibly.  So a repository also comes with a *names* database.  That means a repository can be viewed as *two* databases.  Both are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), with the commits being in the "object database" and found by hash IDs, and the names being in the "names database" and found by their name.  The value you get when you look up a name is a hash ID; looking up a commit hash ID gets Git the commit; and that's how you get a commit.

The *names* in the names database include branch names, tag names, and other such names.  These aren't *branches*, unless by *branch* you mean the things that these are, and then they *are* branches.  So the word *branch*, by itself, means these, except when it doesn't mean these.  (This is why I recommend being careful with the word *branch*.)

So, with that mess temporarily out of the way, let's just concentrate on the raw hash IDs.  When you have *two* repositories, these two repositories can connect to each other.  They can then *share* their commits (using `git fetch` and `git push` for instance), and when they do so, they will all use *the same hash IDs* for the shared commits.  *Different* commits *must* have *different* hash IDs.  The *same* commits, once shared across two separate Git repositories, must have the *same* hash IDs.

What this all means is that the hash ID of any given commit is not just big and ugly, it's also *unique to that one particular commit*.  If you make a *new* commit, your Git software has to give that Git a *unique* hash ID, never used before and never to be used again, anywhere, in any Git repository, ever.  If you then have your Git software *send* that commit to some *other* Git software managing some *other* Git repository, that other Git software *must* use the same hash ID *your* Git just gave to your new commit.

So, it's the *hash IDs* that matter.  Two Git repositories, managed by two different Git software implementations, connect to each other and exchange *commits*, by raw hash ID.

But here's the problem: *humans* can't deal with the raw hash IDs.  We like names!  We think `main` and `dev` and `feature/short` are keen.  But which commit *is* `main`?  Well, *my* `main` is *my* latest commit.  *Your* `main` is *your* latest commit.  If we've both made new commits, *my* `main` and *your* `main` have to translate to *different hash IDs*.

The result is that no Git repository can ever trust any *other* Git repository's *names*.  Each repository has its own private names database, in other words.  But I can connect my Git software to your Git software and *get* your commits *from* you, and when I do that, I would like to know which commit hash ID represents *your* latest `main` commit.

My Git will store this for me, but it won't use the name `main` to do that.  Instead, I'll define what Git calls a *remote*, using `git remote add`:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/you/yourrepo.git
```

for instance.  I can use any name, not just `origin`, and any URL that works for me, so this is just an example; but if I use `git clone` to *copy all of your commits*, my Git software will *automatically* save the URL under the name `origin` by doing this `git remote add` for me, after it creates a new repository.  So `origin` is a pretty common name here.

Anyway, after my Git software connects to yours, I'll get all your commits that are new *to me*—any that we both already have, I already have, and my Git knows this because you and I have the same *hash IDs* here—and my Git software will save them away in my objects database.  Then my Git software will take your *branch names* and *change* them into my *remote-tracking names:* your `main` will become my `origin/main`, your `dev` will become my `origin/dev`, and so on.  Basically my Git sticks my remote name, `origin`, and a slash, in front of your *branch* names.

So once this is all done, I'll have your latest commits, and my Git will turn your *branch names* into my *remote-tracking names*.  To have my Git *list out* my remote-tracking names, I run `git branch -r`.  This lists them as, e.g., `origin/main`.  Or, I use `git branch -a`, which has my Git list out my *branch* names *and* my remote-tracking names; for no obvious reason, Git now lists my remote-tracking names as `remotes/origin/main` and so on.<sup>1</sup>

For all this to work, though, I *must* run `git fetch`.  That's because *my* clone of *your repository* just sits here on my laptop, until I actually do run `git fetch`.  There's no reason for my Git to reach out to yours all the time: I have a *full copy of every version of every file you've ever had* in *my* clone, or at least, as of the *last* time I ran `git fetch`.  All we ever do is *add commits* to a repository, so when you add new commits, I have to run `git fetch` to obtain those new commits.

If your Azure setup has yet *another* clone—if there's a Git repository over on GitHub, for instance, and then you had Azure clone that Git repository to Azure and you've made a new branch name in the Azure clone—well, that didn't affect the *GitHub* clone.  The GitHub clone is its own repository, with its own set of branch names.  You have to get the GitHub clone to fetch from the Azure repository—except that GitHub won't *fetch*.  Instead, you'll have to get the Azure clone to *push* to the GitHub repository.

Pushing is like fetching in that it transfers new commits, but it's also *unlike* fetching.  That is, if I have my own pair of repositories, one on my laptop and one on GitHub, and I make a new commit on my laptop:

```
<edit some files>
git add -u
git commit -m "some terrible commit message"
```

I now have to *send my new commit* to my GitHub clone, using `git push` for instance:

```
git push origin main
```

Here `origin` is the name of the remote, as before, and `main` is the name I use to identify the most recent commit I just made, which is the one I want to send.  My Git software calls up GitHub's Git software and ends up connected to my repository on GitHub, and my software hands over the hash ID of my latest commit.  The GitHub software sees that it does not have that commit—there's nothing in the GitHub repository with that hash ID—so they grab that commit from my Git.  But now the different thing happens:

- My Git software now asks their Git software: *Please, if it's OK, create or update the name `main` in your repository to record this latest commit.*
- They check to see whether it's OK.  It probably is, and if so, they create or update their `main`.

The result is that I've made GitHub update (in this case) their `main` branch-name.  If I make a totally new *name* in my repository:

```
git branch newname
```

I have to run `git push` such that I ask GitHub to (please, if it's OK) create the new name `newname` over there:

```
git push origin newname
```

This time they'll have the latest commit, so the *send new commits* phase of this whole operation does nothing.  But the *please if it's OK create or update a name* phase creates the new branch *name* in the GitHub repository.

Note that I do not have to use the same names in my laptop clone that I use in my GitHub clone.  Each repository has *its own* names database, and if I want, I can create a new branch name `hello` and then have GitHub create instead the name `world`.  I don't normally *want* to do that because it makes things complicated; our feeble human brains can't handle hash IDs and don't do well with using different names on the two sides; we want to just call everything Bruce, to avoid confusion.

---

<sup>1</sup>They have a *full* name, `refs/remotes/origin/main`.  Git normally strips off the `refs/remotes/` part.  But `git branch -a` only strips off the `refs/` part.  Your own branch names also have a full name: `main` is really `refs/heads/main`.  The output from `git branch` or `git branch -a` strips off the `refs/heads/` part, always.

There's a so-called *plumbing command*, `git for-each-ref`, meant for writing new Git commands or other scripts that do something useful, and it normally shows you *every* name, keeping the full `refs/` stuff in the front.  Its output is meant for a computer program to read, though, not for a human, so it's machine-friendly and kind of human-antagonistic.

Comment: Regarding your statement, "we want to just call everything Bruce, to avoid confusion"... that video link is cutoff just before someone says: "Mind if we call you Bruce to keep it clear?" :D

Comment: @TTT: yeah, I had a better link at one time but that was the best version I could find quickly.

Answer (score -1):

If you linked your remote branch you should see them by using `git remote -r` but if its not listed you can check remote origin for that and after that try push on your default branch because that should link your remote all branches that worked for me or you can use that redrence link [here](https://www.nobledesktop.com/learn/git/git-branches)